# Why should we all run away?

Tags: logical-deduction, language

1̡̻̜͎̰͍̺̞̦̗͔̣̘͕͇̩̦̩̽͛̒̅̅̉̉̋͟-̨̧̬͈͓̲̰̦̙̺͙͚̩͈ͦͤ̂̂͂ͦ̾ͨ͆͗̔ͧ͘5̸̸̹͚̬̠͕̞̖͎͚͔̖͍͑͊̂̇ͯͪ̀͠͝ͅ-̶͓̫̝̗̞͚̲̯̹̼͑̐͂̃ͭ̍͆̃͒ͥͭ͊͝1̷̶̛̪̝̺̗͚̮̥͎͇̰̣̻͍̰͕̭ͨ̀͋ͣ̈́ͥ̿̽͑͐̊ͩ͊̅̓͞ͅ;̸͖͈͖̯̦̝̞͚̄̎̆̄̔ͧ̋̿̀͞ ̨̰̹̟̙͂͗̌̓̚͞1̧̢̗͉̠͚̘͙̫̞̟͙̗̗̤̖̘̪̞ͯ̋͊̌ͤͮͨ̅̏ͪͩ̿̅̈́̂͌͒̀́͜-̅ͦ̿̍̆͑҉͏͍͖̼̼̱ͅͅ4̛̻̯͕͉̜̣̳͎͇̮̖̟̻̪̏͐̎ͨ͛ͪ̀̚͜͞͝-̒̓ͧ͊̾̍̋̅̍̂͢҉̰̝̣͖̰̘͕̠̣͇̹̙̲͕̘͚5̡͖̤͔͔̼͚̗̯̯̬̦̬̦̠̫̙͇̜̍͆̐ͪ̃ͧ̊̇͐͗̍͛̃͜͜;̯̝̼̟̰̬̳͍̳̬̗̜̙̈́̆͐͆́̿ͣͣ̐̋͊ͩ̊͒ͤ͂̾̎̕͟ͅ ̶̞̭̪̜͔͈͇̱͕̭̳̟͎̱ͭͬ̈́̃̓͗͂̆̆̓͞͠ͅͅ2̸̥̘͙͓̰͔͇͈̄͒̂̎̀̑̌̋͑̿ͫͬ̓͌̈́̌̄̾́͝-̴͖̳̝̳̗̂͑ͫͧ͌̉ͦͦ͊̈̍ͣ̅ͧͨ̚2̷̧̮͇̟͖̦̫͍̥̍̆͊ͣ̍̈͂ͮ̊͂͞͞-̸̡͕̭̤͔͓̯̭̤͋͒͑͌ͧ͐͝3̨̢͖̲͖̗̻̩̖̹̤͈ͮͣ͋̓͐ͧ́̄͐͋́̚̚;̐͆ͨ͌̌ͭ̇̚҉̝͍̖̰͈̯̟̯̯̻ͅ ̸̭̮̰̰̮̼̬͇̲̼̤̽ͧ̓͐͐̐ͥ̌̋̆̀̎̏̈͑͛ͯ̐̂͘͘͟͡1̸̡̛̫̥̖͖͓͍͇͛͆̐̂̍̏̋̅̏̾ͭ̇̔́̚͞-̴̏ͤ̒ͮͫ͊̏ͩ̎̏ͯͯ̏͊̀͊̉̀҉҉̮̼̳̟͖͚̘̖͙͇͙͓̝͍͎̳̜̯͞ͅ4̋͂̊̽҉̶̡͙̺͕̙͎͓̪͙̙͉̲̙̠͘-̵̡͔͚͚̒͐̒ͦ̐̊̇̽ͯ̋̏ͮ̉͊̂͆͐̌͟͞ͅ9̸̶̖͉̲̜̯̗͎͕̤̖̞̆̄ͧ̾͆̈́̄͛ͧ̈;̓̄́͆̍ͣͨ̌ͥ̃́ͤ̈̿͠҉͓̲̼̗̙͍̼̗̩̰͎͢ ̴̛̻̜̝̼͕͉͂̄͋̇ͫͭ̊̓̍ͥ̓̚͠ͅ1̴̛̛̗̲̩̖̖̱̖̖̳̳̮̬̘̓ͦͦ͆͂̃ͣ͌͋ͤ̅̽̚͞͠-̍̍̈́ͨ͗ͯ̊͏̢̡̟͈̗͍̰̤̭͔͓̫͔̻͖͔̭͘4̷̢̛̙͓̹̜̞̖̳̹̹ͨ̑̉̎̂ͬͮ̈̓ͥ͗̀ͫ̀̚͘-̅̀ͭ̏̋ͨ̌͆̈ͥ͜҉̬̦̬͖̘̘7̶̢͖̞̟̤̮ͬ̈͒ͩ͋̊͌͋ͧ̏̊͂̚̕͟;̨͍̤̗̲̹̯̮͓̯̤͉̣͈͖̥̓̑̾͒͆ͬ͟͟ͅͅ ̸̠̤͔͚͕̟͚̪̞͔̑̈̍̅̐̈́̾ͤ̈́̊̑͋̆͌͛͗̋̋1ͯ͑̒͆҉̝͙̰͚͎̪̱̟̦͍̣̩̪͚-̵̴͉̭̠̹̔͆̈ͬ͋̂̌̏͊̾ͦͦͮ̏̐̓ͩ́̚͡5̸̧͎̞͉̗̦̬̦̹̞̙̩̤̗͉̗̂ͫ́ͦ̋̑̋͐̊ͣ͗ͪ̾͋ͫͦ͘͝͠-̛̋͐̿̐̑̓̒͒̍͐͛̆ͯ̽̃̀͡͏͈͖̟̟͎͔̠͖̬̹̬̼̲͕͓̞͉͕́2̸̢ͩ̽̈́ͫͤ̎̔̇́͐̂ͫ̾͒̌҉̸̰̦͇̱̣̖̻̬̞;́͆ͮͭ́͌҉͍͍̻̜͙͕ ͍̳̗̠̬̥̹̟̜̍ͣ̄ͦͤ͢͟1̵̥͖̖̹̱̫̦̣̠̦̲̺̐͑̈͒ͦ̅̊̿̋̾̀̀͒͢-̵͇͖̭͎̭̻̼̼̞̤̮̑̋ͬͬ̅̈́̒͌̀ͯ́͡4̸̧̱̠̣̹͇̣͔̇͑̔ͫ̈́̔̑̕-̸̛͕̙͖̻̦̙̙̼͖ͤ̒ͨ͋͌ͨ͢͠5̴̴̥͓̙̗̜̗͎́ͬ̐ͧ̆̿͋͑̓̽ͧ̚͘͡;̶̧̛͕̱͚̼̞̦̩̺̰̤̙̻̱͚̾͊̈͛̃̓ͭ͛͐̽̑ͬͫ̋̔ͅ ̵̃̐̂̏͏̱̩̬̞̲̗̦͈̮̰͠1̵̼͖̱̘̠̦̹͕̝͇̯̿ͬ̉̒̈ͩ̽͞-̵ͥ̎̒́̈́̀͂͆ͦ̏͛ͤ̋͌̔͗͛͢͏͏̝̞͇̮͔5̸̞̩͇͖̱̱̝̫̲͕̣̺͕̘̳͈̗͐̒̇ͥ̋̀ͫ͐̂̾ͤ̄ͨ̓͂̓ͣͨ̃̕͘͡͝-̴̷͔͉̯͓͙͓̀̾ͯ͊̇̎̑͗ͬ͛͐̏ͤ̚͢ͅ4̷̧̫̰̻̰̺̖̳̥̖̼͚͇͍͊̓̒̉͂ͮͪ̂͌ͣͫ̿͒̉̚͟;̩͕͈͓̩̻͉͇̣ͪ͊̋̎͐͆ͤ̀̍ͭ̐͐͢͢͟͢ ͕͈̲̥̠̦̝̫̭̮͎͇̪͉͎͕͔̞̯̉̿̉͐͊̾ͦͯ͑ͬ͑ͨ̏ͧͫ͂̓͜͜͜͠1̵̵̛̫̰͙̼̙̺͆͊̑͂̈́̒ͨ̏̄̑ͤ̐͟ͅ-̎̊̑ͣ̿̏̏̋͒̆̃̈́̚͏̡̛͉̲̰͓̠̖̪̼͉̥̰͔̙5̴̡̼̰̘̠̯͍͈̾̎͗̌͋̎͑̋͊ͬ̒̽̈́-̸̨̩̖͕̯̹͉͔̳̺͖̭̣̫̼̆ͯ͛̇̄̒ͦ͘1̸̸̵̯̻͙͇̦̥̫̲̻̰̦͙̳̝̱͇̰͚̓̿ͥͣ͋̈́̅͌̓ͩ̀ͦ̒ͦ͊̈̽͢͢

.
.
HINT 1: (the 2 dots above this line were needed to make the hint readable)

> Are you feeling lucky?

HINT 2:

> It has to do with Zalgo's characters, but not with the characters displayed here

Comment: +1 because i did not know we could type like this..

Comment: ... Because Zalgo i̲͎͒͝ṡ̡̱͝ ̨̹̓̐c̨̜̃́ō̱̖̂m̛̹̣͋į̣̓͝ṉ͚̇̚g̢̭̈́̕ ? Or are we actually supposed to do something using e.g. the specific numbers in the text here? (And ... is "logical-deduction" really the right tag for this?)

Comment: Yes you are supposed to do something with them :D And... well, I guess the tag is correct

Comment: To save others some trouble: stripping off all the exotic characters appears to yield `151;145;223;149;147;152;145;154;151`. (I have no way of knowing whether stripping them off is the intended first step, or whether it throws away information essential for solving the puzzle.)

Comment: 151145223149147152145154151

Comment: The numbers are in the range from 145 to 223. Taking the 8-bit complement (by xoring with or subtracting from 255) and interpreting it as ASCII gives "hn jlgneh", which could be an encoded answer. I don't think that the Zalgo stuff carries any useful information, but when I stripped it, I got the numbers in the format 1-5-1; 1-4-5; and so on.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan also note that there are spaces between the semicolons. I dunno if that's important, but it appears to show more clearly that they are separate numbers.

Comment: Also, those numbers as cp437 (aka extended ascii) codepoints: "ùæ▀òôÿæÜù" And as latin-1 codepoints: "—‘ß•“˜‘š—". UTF-8 is the same as latin-1.

Comment: I'm dubious that all that data in the Zalgo noise isn't at all useful. We should at least look at the character values: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/how-does-zalgo-text-work

Comment: Unicode analysis: https://rawgit.com/jdunk/6522a92985456b869c766bca5fda839f/raw/a2dfdce728ce5ffe3a9b3d87d35d7bdc01127de0/why_should_we_all_run_away.html 
(Tool I used: http://output.jsbin.com/erajer)

Comment: I think some of you already gave everyone else more than a single hint, so I'll let you lot think about it a little more :)

Comment: If Zalgo extra characters are not giving any information, and since the question never mentions Zalgo, I'd bet it is the word to decrypt hn jlgneh

Comment: @AlbertMasclans "The question never mentions Zalgo" is correct, but the text of the puzzle does, since it is written in Zalgo :P

Comment: It's been... *que music*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

well …

> First copy text into https://eeemo.net/ and remove zalgo -
>  1-5-1; 1-4-5; 2-2-3; 1-4-9; 1-4-7; 1-5-2; 1-4-5; 1-5-4; 1-5-1
>  if you look at https://eeemo.net/ reference sheet
>  and take 151 = first table, 5th row, 1st column - h
>  145 - e
>  223 -
>  149 - c
>  147 - o
>  152 - m
>  145 - e
>  154 - t
>  151 - h
>  = he cometh?
>  and thats why should we all run away…

Comment: Was too easy with the hints :P wasn't it?

Comment: I think everyone expected something more complicated like alt+151 or alt+0151, unicode tables etc.

Comment: Well no one got it until the second hint... so I guess it **was** complicated :P